# Why does everyone in Harry Potter make a giant cauldron of potion?

Tags: harry-potter, potions

Everyone takes Potions in Harry Potter . . . but why does everyone make a giant pot of potion each time? The final result is a small vial that is nowhere near the size of the cauldron. Besides the disproportionate potion vs. vial amount, making such a large amount seems like a waste of materials.

Is there an explanation for why the ***students*** make so much?

***Note:*** Not asking about professional potion brewers (as @Adamant points out in comments) who make a lot for reasons such as selling.

Comment: I think Rowling & co were simply invoking a pre-existing trope. I think if you look at other depictions of potion-brewing which pre-date Harry Potter, you'll find the same sort of thing - a generously-sized cauldron, almost brimming over with brew, from which only a tiny portion, sometimes just a few drops are drawn off to be administered.

Comment: And of course people who brewed actual mundane potions sometimes did so in large batches because that was often a source of income, so they sold potions to many people, and because some ingredients were seasonal, perishable, or limited, so it was easier to store the potions than the raw ingredients. Also, sometimes they only had the one pot, and they had to have one big enough for soup!

Comment: @Adamant My specification is students, but all your points are noteworthy (especially the soup one).

Comment: Just guessing, but maybe the active part of the potion is usually in an oily layer floating at the top, and wizards haven't invented sep funnels. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separatory_funnel

Comment: Don't recall any mention of cauldron actual physical sizes in the book but in the films it might be that it's easier to film when they use larger cauldrons

Comment: When I was in grade school, a lab partner and I botched an experiment mid way through and ended up doubling the components. This had the unintended side effect of making our calculations twice as accurate as everyone else's. Perhaps to get potions right you must be very accurate with the proportions and small batches lead to larger errors. Off by one drop when 10 are required vs off by one drop when 100 are required because you are baking a batch an order of magnitude larger.

Comment: This is 100% speculation, but perhaps there's a "reduction" step that's undepicted.  It's not uncommon in cooking, for example, to simmer to reduce a liquid by a significant fraction to thicken it, or to concentrate the flavor.  Perhaps a similar mechanism reduces the potion to intensify the effect, or make it more convenient to administer (if a whole cauldron results in a dose or two, that's a highly inconvenient volume to both transport and/or consume when needed).

Comment: @SpacePhoenix Vague memory:  Weren't they just the right size to carry books in, when they were in Diagon Alley?  I think that was how Tom Riddle's diary was slipped in with the others.

Comment: Real-world nuclear stuff can have properties like "_critical mass_", where the amount of material matters.  Maybe magic might too?

Comment: Note that real-world chemical-reactors don't tend to trivially scale -- this is, a chemical-reactor can't just have all of its dimensions doubled and be expected to work.  The simplest chemical-reactors, i.e. batch-reactors without significant heating or other effects and in which everything's well-mixed, can be an exception.

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm I thought something similar, but can't say whether it fits in the HP universe: Consider how much sap must be boiled to make maple syrup.

Comment: Because modern laboratory glassware wasn't invented until the early 1800s, long after wizarding society ossified.

Comment: Inexplicable quantities sounds like magic to me...

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm I doubt simple reduction would work, I was thinking more along the lines of distillation.

Comment: @LorenPechtel yeah, there's a reason I prefaced with "this is 100% speculation".  I mean, I can't help that (at the time of this writing) 17 other people thought it was a worthy notion, but if I was more confident in it, I'd have put up an answer to get shot down.

Comment: @Theodore if I'm honest, I get a little weary of these "stories not set in reality must be explainable exclusively by reality and made to make sense to me and my reality-grounded thinking" sorts of queries.  Just enjoy the story (or apply the Rule of Cool) and move on...the author gave you what they gave you.  There's no prize for "catching them out" or playing "stump the chump".

Comment: @CaptAlgorithm I wasn't criticizing your idea, only explaining why I didn't put a similar one into an answer.

Comment: The cost (in terms of resources) to make a potion is probably the reason why no wizard created a business to sell potions to Muggles.

Comment: [Relevant question on Worldbuilding Stack Exchange](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/214194/why-are-potions-always-brewed-in-extreme-bulk)

Answer (score 91, accepted):

It's quite possible that some recipes don't divide well. Have you ever tried to halve a recipe that calls for 1 egg? It can be done, but it's a bit annoying and cannot be done without physically modifying the ingredient. Quite a number of potion ingredients are things that may be not so easily divisible like eggs, eyes, or entire creatures or specific body parts. Anything that is not a homogeneous substance like a liquid or powder may be damaged by splitting or not work as well in the potion - imagine trying to halve the recipe for a hard-boiled egg!

For these reasons, recipes that call for 1 of something indivisible may not usually be made in smaller quantities. Since some recipes aren't easily divisible, it may not be common practice to divide any recipes, which may typically taught in standard cauldron quantities.

Comment: This useful analogy between magic potions and kitchen recipes suggests an additional possible reason: heating to a precise temperature a small quantity of liquid (think milk or custard) is more difficult than working with a larger batch, because the temperature grows more quickly.

Comment: You make a very compelling point which I agree with, @nuclearhoagie . Do you have a source for the recipes being taught in cauldron-worths?

Comment: It's also possible that it cooks down a lot.  If I need a half a cup of cooked spinach, I'm starting with a lot more than that in raw leaves.

Comment: This. I would imagine that certain ingredients would be indivisible for magical reasons, in the sense that they are only effective if added intact, and prematurely "tearing a piece off" would undermine or invalidate their efficacy.

Comment: Even if the recipe needed only homogeneous substances in powder or liquid form but needed it in extremely small quantities, it would be very difficult to measure to a sufficient accuracy if you only brew a small dose (especially by children, especially without modern tools). And in case of *magical* potions, if you are not accurate enough with your measurements, the magic could backfire (which we often see in several occasions). Potion-making is explicitly depicted as very dangerous in the HP universe if you make even the smallest mistake.

Comment: This answer would benefit greatly from evidence from the Harry Potter universe. As it is, it's speculative at best and could apply to worldbuilding any magical world.

Comment: @lfurini So it's double the trouble to burn fire to make cauldrons bubble?

Answer (score 22):

As alluded to in comments, I suspect that the reduced error from scale may also play into it. Some of the ingredients added to the potions are fairly small amounts, and we see in the books that small differences sometimes seem to have large effects. If you need to add five drops of liquid to a gallon of potion material in the student recipe, scaling that down to, say, 8 oz, means that one accidental extra drop makes much more of a difference than one off from five.

As to the waste, wizards never seem to think too much about that. There are huge tables of food created out of thin air for each of the meals. Snape routinely disappears the contents of the cauldron, an effect noted to return the material into nothingness. Either something in the nature of magic means that there's some degree of recycling going on, at least to preserve a conservation of mass and energy, or the wizards just don't care, possibly because they don't understand the potential implications of their actions.

Comment: Food cannot be conjured out of thin air (Gamp's Law of Elemental Transfiguration ...), I seem to remember meals at Hogwarts are just teleported from the kitchens to the tables. Apart from this, I agree with the rest of the answer.

Comment: Food can be duplicated out of "thin air", though. You have a sandwich and you can duplicate it multiple times.

Comment: I think Snape's "disappearing the contents of the cauldron" might be more akin to him Disapparating it somewhere rather than destroying it, similar to how Wizards would Disapparate their own stool in the halls of Hogwarts before they introduced plumbing.

Comment: @jo1storm but then u already had a sandwich. how often will you be able to copy it until it is spoiled? i guess you can create ingredients out of nothing or transmute something into ingredients. i'm not entirely sure why this rule is needed in the world, tho. other universes have evokers who call matter into existence, or use a form of energy-conservation where you can't create something without sacrificing something else. but in the wizarding world, i guess you can't evoke food. maybe to always have an option for poisoning or the like

Comment: @clockw0rk yes, but that was my point. The rules don't make sense. I guess the house elves would make a single perfect baked chicken and duplicate it a thousand times then serve it upstairs? Or they would make a single perfect bread loaf and do the same? Except nobody mentions that. And it also begs the question of why didn't wizards solve the world hunger already if that is the case.

Answer (score 10):

In some few cases the potion will be the result of reducing through boiling for a long time. This is somewhat like maple syrup. You boil it for a long time to concentrate the non-water ingredients, as well as producing a small amount of oxidation to produce the color and taste. You must boil 40 gallons of sap down to 1 gallon of maple syrup.

Answer (score 10):

Magic in Harry Potter is quite often rather *symbolic* in how it works. I think that, when it comes to potions, this means that the size of the batch matters; like, if you're adding 7 pinches of dried nettles, maybe it's important that it is specifically **7** pinches as the potion invokes the connection between power and nr 7. This would make potions akin to simple rituals, and neatly explains why you have to brew a specific amount each time.

Answer (score 3):

As rightly pointed out by others, Rowling seems to have invoked a pre-existing trope, and all we can do is look for post hoc rationalisations.

One additional possibility that comes to mind is that boiling large quantities of potions is the skill that wizards will normally need as adults and hence the skill that they want to be learning as students. It stands to reason that an adult making a potion is most likely either a) working as a professional brewer or b) preparing a large batch of a potion they need regularly - otherwise it's probably more efficient to just pop to the Diagon Ally and buy a vial. In analogy with cooking, preparing a tiny cauldron of a potion is probably similar but not identical skill to preparing a regular size cauldron, and quite possibly a more difficult one in some ways (and possibly easier in ways). Thus, if you're going to be making large portions as an adult, you might as well make large portions as a kid. Admittedly it's a bit more wasteful than preparing small portions, but students wouldn't be preparing expensive potions to begin with, and any quantity of the potions that they make is going to be wasted anyways.

Answer (score 0):

Some other good answers here, but I can add another reason for this: sometimes, in cooking, you separate out parts of a mixture. For example, I have a cousin who makes her own yogurt, and part of the process involves separating the whey from the remainder. Or, if I'm cooking bacon, I may save the bacon grease for later use.

It reminds me of my high school chemistry class, where we learned some reactions will form a precipitate. It may be the small amount of precipitate is what you need, and you use a larger container in order to skim off just a few ounces of the final desired mixture.